# Spacemacs editor - Razor syntax highlight (*.cshtml files)

Tags: razor, emacs, syntax-highlighting, spacemacs

Is there syntax highlighting for Razor views (*.cshtml files) available in Spacemacs?

I have csharp layer installed. Syntax highlighting works with *.cs files but no with *.cshtml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[web-mode](http://web-mode.org/) works pretty well for `.cshtml`, except for code blocks within the template.